# How to keep generated source code for proto files in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have studied https://blog.bazel.build/2017/02/27/protocol-buffers.html . The project I want to hack on is written in Go. At the moment, if I run the build command I can see the compiled binary but I don't see the *.pb.go files anywhere. I want to keep the generated *.pb.go files in the same folder where *.proto files are so that my IDE (Intellij Goland) can find and index them.

Can you please help me how to get this working? If you can show me how to do that for the `github.com/cgrushko/proto_library` project, I should be able to try that in my particular project.

Answer (score 3):

Bazel will not output generated files (such as `.pb.go`) into the source tree. They go into the output directories (`bazel-out/<config>` or `bazel-genfiles/<config>`). Temporary solution might be to add those as source roots to goland. The real solution is to use https://ij.bazel.build/. It has some Go support, and the team is actively working on improving it.

Comment: Thank Dmitry! I installed the Bazel plugin but it does not work with Goland since I don't have Junit plugin.